I Think I Trisected an Angle,

I started with a $40^\circ$ angle:



I then copied that to the other side with a compass, I then added a perpendicular line on each side to make it a right triangle, making sure both are the same length:



I then drew a triangle with the width of the other two triangles, and with a height double that of the other triangles:



Then, I drew a fourth triangle with the height of the small and large triangle combined, and the length of three times the small triangle:



Then, I drew an arc on a circle with a radius of the width of the two small triangles, and it intersected the largest triangle:



I copy the triangle to the right:



I draw a segment from the intersection of the arc and the largest triangle to the furthest right point of the furthest triangle:



But then, the angle from the base and the segment just drawn is $~9^\circ$, and the other is $~30^\circ$:


I'm confused as to why they aren't equal, as the largest triangle is being split into 2 parts, one is 1/3 of it, the other is 2/3

Welcome to Math.SE! ... The upshot of your question is (referencing your final figure): In isosceles $\triangle QJK$ with $O$ on $\overline{JK}$ such that $|OK|=\frac13|JK|$, why isn't $\angle OQK=\frac13\angle JQK$? The short answer is that trisecting lengths and trisecting angles almost-never agree like that. (There's one magic angle (about $62.1^\circ$) where this strategy does work.) We shouldn't really expect this to happen, anyway. After all, a median of a triangle —which joins a vertex to the midpoint of the opposite side, bisecting that side— typically doesn't bisect an angle.

Please refer to my simplified diagram. 
Hence from my diagram, by properties of parallel lines,$$\angle ABC=40°$$
$$BE=4+2+2+2=10 \ \text{units}$$
$$ED=2\tan 40°$$
Hence $$\tan \angle EBD =\frac{ED}{BE}=\frac{2\tan 40°}{10}$$
$$\implies \angle EBD=\arctan\bigg(\frac{\tan 40°}{5}\bigg)=9.5266°$$
Thus $\angle ABD=40°-9.5266°=30.4733°$.
You're not essentially trisecting the angle. You're actually trisecting the side $AB$. If you measure it, $CD=2\cos 40°,AD=4\cos 40°$.

To anyone wondering why this paper is so crooked, I drew this diagram on the back of a question paper, and I didn't have a ruler. I used my comb. Hence the diagram is not to scale :)
